# Is there a way to access the value of a classical bit after measurement and store it as a variable (qiskit)?

Tags: qiskit, measurement, shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

I am trying to implement the one-qubit Approximate QFT for Shor's Algorithm in qiskit as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001066.pdf), which requires the gate
$$
R_j^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \hspace{0.5em} 0 \\
0 \hspace{0.5em} \phi_j^{\prime}
\end{array}\right) \text { with } \phi_j^{\prime}=e^{-2 \pi i \sum_{k=2}^j m_{j-k} / 2^k}
$$
in the circuit [image: AQFT with one qubit]

The variable $ m_{j-k} $ is a previous measurement result, so an array of previous results would be useful. 
The alternative is to store each measurement in a separate classical bit and get the value of the register as a whole. As of now, the only way I know to access the classical register to implement gates is by using `.c_if(c, val)`, which means that I will need to attach a `c_if` for every possible value of the classical register in order to construct the gate, creating way too many gates.
Is there a way I can get the value of the classical register and store it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you considered something like this already, but you may try to look at the state of the qubit that was measured. Then you check: if the state is $|0\rangle$, you append the number "0" to an array "m"; conversely, if the state is $|1\rangle$, you append the number "1".

I haven't seen you code, but I've made a simple one myself in order to illustrate. Try to run it a few times.

```
from qiskit import BasicAer, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

# Function that returns the state vector of a circuit

backend = BasicAer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")

def Simulate_statevector(q_circuit):
    tqc = transpile(q_circuit, backend)
    job = backend.run(tqc)
    result = job.result()
    psi_qc = result.get_statevector(tqc, 4)
    return Statevector(psi_qc)

from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit

qubits = QuantumRegister(2)
cbits = ClassicalRegister(2)

qc = QuantumCircuit(qubits, cbits)

qc.h(1) # Applying a H gate so that measurement in qubit 1 can return either |0> or |1>

m = [] # Array to store measurement outcomes

# Measuring qubit 1
qc.measure(1, 1)

# Getting the state vector of the circuit
Psi = Simulate_statevector(qc)

# Storing measurement outcome
if Psi[0].real == 1:
    m.append(0)
    
else:
    m.append(1)

print('m =', m)
Psi.draw('latex')
```

I hope it was useful.